# Optimal data type for storing numbers in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, datatypes, disk-space, standard-edition

Similar to varchar that stores strings of varying length, is there an alternative for numbers of varying length that allocates space depending on the size of the number?

I have a large table with 50 columns holding about a billion rows including 15 numeric(10) columns. My quick proof of concept with 4 million showed that I can save a bit of disk-space by reducing the size of these 15 columns, hence this question. Please advise.

POC details - I reduced the column size from numeric(22) to numeric(5) for 15 columns with 3.5 mil rows and disk usage dropped from 1398.02 MB to 981.23 MB.
I will have to push this up to numeric(10) as size 5 will not suffice.

Note: numeric(22) was a bad design I inherited. Changing to integer data type reduced disk usage even further - 907.27 MB. Integer should help if our data model standards team allows this [since it contains no precision]. Will keep posted.

The server version and edition is

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64) Jun 17
>   2016 19:14:09 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Neither `vardecimal` or compression are available to you.

Comment: Good to know about vardecimal, thank you Martin.

Answer (score 1):

You can use row compression [Row Compression Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/row-compression-implementation) that in designed to solve exactly this problem.

And you can also think about page compression that first applies row compression and then tries to achieve space savings using dictionary

Update: available also in Standard started with **SQL Server 2016 SP1**

Comment: Okay, thanks for the feedback, I'm missing out here on the version.